# Django: When form is submitted, auto-fill a field

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I'm looking to auto-fill a field when I submit a form so it is identical to another field.

I have a createView with a modelForm. The idea is the user writes his/hers name, which then when submitted fills out the display_name field as well. I know it's weird "why have two of the same", but it has a purpose.

Here's my code - I'm guessing I need to create a context that gets the display_name and sets it to be equal to the name?

### views.py

```
class CreateIdentity(CreateView):
    template_name = 'admin/CreateIdentity.html'
    model = Identity
    form_class = CreateIdentityForm
    queryset = Identity.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateIdentity, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["user_id"] = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user)  
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_id = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy("view_identity_created_with_slug", kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})
```

### models.py

```
class Identity(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column="username", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)
```

### forms.py

```
class CreateIdentityForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'spellcheck': "false",
        "class": "identity_name_input",
        'placeholder': "Write your identity"}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Identity
        fields = ["name"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Comment: So if it is filled in, it overrides it, right? Can you share the `CreateIdentityForm`?

Comment: Well initially, it will not have a value, thus I want it to have the value of what the name is, but when it is able to be edited later on, yes that value will be overridden, if that makes sense? I will update with the ModelForm shortly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [**`.form_valid(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid), you can specify the `display_name` based on the cleaned data of the `form`:

```
class CreateIdentity(CreateView):
    template_name = 'admin/CreateIdentity.html'
    model = Identity
    form_class = CreateIdentityForm
    queryset = Identity.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateIdentity, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["user_id"] = User.objects.get(username=self.request.user)  
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user_id = self.request.user
        form.instance.display_name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy("view_identity_created_with_slug", kwargs={'slug': self.object.slug})
```

Comment: Super, this is perfect, thank you. I was pretty close..damn..I will have to read about cleaned_data, uncertain what it's purpose is. I will accept your answer shortly. :)